# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'dataset/var/UCF-101\\train\\ApplyEyeMakeup'

Tags: python, pytorch

Device being used: cpu

Training R3D from scratch...

Total params: 33.23M

Training model on ucf101 dataset...

Preprocessing of ucf101 dataset, this will take long, but it will be done only once.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 202, in <module>
    train_model()
  File "train.py", li`enter code here`ne 97, in train_model
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(VideoDataset(dataset=dataset, split='train',clip_len=16), batch_size=20, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
  File "C:\pytorch-video-recognition\dataloaders\dataset.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.preprocess()
  File "C:\pytorch-video-recognition\dataloaders\dataset.py", line 136, in preprocess
    os.mkdir(train_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'dataset/var/UCF-101\\train\\ApplyEyeMakeup'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite evident from the stack trace.

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'dataset/var/UCF-101\train\ApplyEyeMakeup'

This location is supposed to contain your data file. But, it is not available for some reason.

Comment: data is present in that folder. I've tried that way

Answer (score 0):

The path for the file seems false since it is: `'dataset/var/UCF-101\\train\\ApplyEyeMakeup'`. It should instead be `'dataset/var/UCF-101/train/ApplyEyeMakeup'` these two right back slashes are what causing a problem I guess. *See escape characters*.

Comment: I've tried both slashes none of them works

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it still the same error or has it changed?